# MySQL Won't let User Login: Error 1524

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Server version: 5.7.10 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

In MySQL, I have a user mangos. The user worked perfectly when I created it. After rebooting my computer, though, attempting to login to mangos yielded this output:

```
$ mysql -u mangos -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin '*some_random_long_hash_I_cannot_remember' is not loaded
$
```

It kind of reminded me of a password hash, so after investigating mysql.user, I found that mangos had no password!
I updated the password:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'mangos'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('mangos');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now, I get:

```
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin '*3FBBDB84EA2B2A0EA599948396AD622B7FF68183' is not loaded
```

`3FBBDB84EA2B2A0EA599948396AD622B7FF68183` is the same number shown in the password column of mysql.user for mangos, and is a different number than originally. I still can't log in.

**How do I make MySQL recognize a password properly?** Is that even the issue here?

*Edits:*

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'mangos' \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Host: localhost
              User: mangos
          Password: *3FBBDB84EA2B2A0EA599948396AD622B7FF68183
       Select_priv: N
       Insert_priv: N
       Update_priv: N
       Delete_priv: N
       Create_priv: N
         Drop_priv: N
       Reload_priv: N
     Shutdown_priv: N
      Process_priv: N
         File_priv: N
        Grant_priv: N
   References_priv: N
        Index_priv: N
        Alter_priv: N
      Show_db_priv: N
        Super_priv: N
Create_tmp_table_priv: N
      Lock_tables_priv: N
          Execute_priv: N
       Repl_slave_priv: N
      Repl_client_priv: N
      Create_view_priv: N
        Show_view_priv: N
   Create_routine_priv: N
    Alter_routine_priv: N
      Create_user_priv: N
            Event_priv: N
          Trigger_priv: N
Create_tablespace_priv: N
              ssl_type: 
            ssl_cipher: 
           x509_issuer: 
          x509_subject: 
         max_questions: 0
           max_updates: 0
       max_connections: 0
  max_user_connections: 0
                plugin: *3FBBDB84EA2B2A0EA599948396AD622B7FF68183
 authentication_string: NULL
      password_expired: N
```

Comment: Have you been entering users directly into the users table? What does this have to say? `SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'mangos' \G`

Comment: That string `*3FBB...` definitely looks like a password hash. Since you can login as a different user (to run the `SET PASSWORD`, I would recommend you run a query of the `mysql.user` table, and look at the contents of the **`plugin`** column. It contains `mysql_native_password` on my MySQL 5.6 database, for users that authenticate by password. The error message make it look like MySQL is looking for an authorization plugin other than `mysql_native_password`, and isn't finding it. (It looks to me like someone did an `update mysql.user set plugin = PASSWORD('foo') where user='mangos'`

Comment: @spencer7593 I updated the question with all of the info form the user; I definitely think you're on to something there. On my root user, plugin is indeed mysql_native_password and not a hash.

Comment: @miken32 I don't remember ever putting in a user manually, I am pretty sure I used the builtin functionality (obviously not correctly). I did have a bunch of sketchy scripts setting up the tables, though, and they may not have conformed to the best practices (especially for my pretty-new version of MySQL)

Comment: I recommend you run **`update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where user = 'mangos' and host = 'localhost'`**  followed by a **`flush privileges`**.

Comment: @spencer7593 I did as you said, and `plugin: mysql_native_password` looks right. Still get access denied to log in to the user, though.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It appears your user table is corrupted. Likely the reboot you mentioned triggered an upgrade to MySQL and the `mysql_upgrade` script was not run. This should resolve the situation:

```bash
mysql_upgrade -u root -ppassword --skip-grant-tables
mysql -u root -ppassword -e "UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'mangos'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
```

Source: [http://kb.odin.com/en/126676](https://web.archive.org/web/20160221002152/http://kb.odin.com/en/126676)

Providing the `--force` option to `mysql_upgrade` will re-apply the upgrade scripts even if an upgrade has already been done. This may be needed in case of partial restoration from backup.

Also worth mentioning, the command to change a user password has changed in [MySQL 5.7.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html) / [MariaDB 10.2.0](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-user/) and forward:

```
ALTER USER mangos IDENTIFIED BY 'mangos';
```

This is now the preferred method for setting the password, although the older `SET PASSWORD` syntax is not officially deprecated.

Comment: Hmm, was MySQL upgraded during the reboot? Maybe run mysql_upgrade and check your system logs? Also your client is the same version as your server?

Comment: I too suspect that `mysql_upgrade` wasn't run after the install of a different version of MySQL. Or, if it was run, it failed (we'd expect it would have generated some errors.)

Comment: I just skipped grant tables and upgraded.
It upgraded a bunch of stuff and it says it was successful. I still can't log into that one user though. I'll try and remake it again. @spencer7593 What logs specifically should I provide?

Comment: @spencer7593 Ah, ok. I `mysql_upgrade`ed, dropped mangos, made it again, and was able to log in. Everything is working as it should.

Comment: It's worth noting that `plugin: mysql_native_password' is what was generated in user after the upgrade

Comment: Yes, it does basic password checks; I believe that with default settings, "mangos" would have failed those checks so figured I'd just leave it out.

Comment: Ok cool. If you would edit your answer really quick and mention upgrading, and mysql_native_password, I'll select it. If you don't, I'll probably still select it. Thanks so much!

Comment: For the record: I needed to do a forced `mysql_upgrade -u root -v -f (force)` and then the error was gone. (Did need some changes to phpmyadmin and tables though to make everything work 100%)

Comment: Tried the command from the original reply, and the one from @e-motiv, in both cases I get the following:  \bin>mysql_upgrade -u root --force
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1524: Plugin '*3341D225A70FDF32F7D6E158192BF9A65654BE7F' is not loaded while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.

Comment: Try to delete the values in the MySQL users column named plug-in before updating. But save the values first as they are the encrypted passwords. (Careful! I don't take responsability!)

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_upgrade` (suggested by @miken32) wasn't working for me, so I had to do it the hard way, by shutting down the service and using `mysqld_safe`, as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489098/unable-to-reset-root-password-of-mysql/671593#671593).

**UPDATE**: Actually, that didn't work either, so I had to do the hard hard hard way (beware, **this deletes all your databases**):

1. `sudo killall mysqld`
2. `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql`
3. `sudo apt-get purge mysql-server`
4. Install `mysql-server` package again.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue resolved from **[here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/10/plugin-not-loaded-mysql.html)**. Run `mysql_upgrade -u root -p` to fix the issue or if you are facing this error while creating a user than try using "**BY**" instead of "**WITH**" in your query.

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xyz';
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line to the my.ini file and it worked perfectly :

```
[mysqld]
#Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir = "C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-binaries/dbserver/mysql5717x86x191205223118/"

skip-grant-tables <=== added this line
```

Hope it helps,

cheers

Answer (score -1):

I came across this issue on a 5.7.12 box that was replicating from a 5.6 box.  The 5.6 box had been downgraded from 5.7 as it's part of a pre-prod test environment.

As part of the downgrade process, the 5.6 box got it's permissions screwed (run mysql_upgrade --force on 5.6 after a downgrade solves it) but in the process it appears that some of the permissions changes issued on the 5.6 server were pushed to the 5.7 server.

Ultimately, the authentication_string password hash ended up in the plugin column for root@localhost.

Fixing moving the hash to the correct column and inserting the mysql_native_password into the 'plugin' column for that user cured the problem.

I'm now working on replicating the issue so I can submit a bug report, but there were a number of factors involved so it's proving hard to replicate.