# EasyPhp - Receive "Missing Plugin" Error When Attempting to Grant Permissions

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I've just installed EasyPHP and in the MySQL section I created a new user called "foo" and checked the box to give it all privileges.  When I click on the tab to manage the MySQL user accounts the user "foo" is there.  But it shows foo's level of privileges only as "USAGE", and when I mouseover that word it says, "no privileges".

So I tried to update the privileges for foo.  But when I try to edit them I get the error

> "#1524 - Plugin '*E394918EB0645561038DD951D0CABA8042DDFE14' is not
>   loaded".

Interestingly, when I go back to the tab for user accounts and mouseover the "root" user it states

> "Includes all privileges except GRANT"

Maybe this is why it can't grant "foo" any privileges?

Any idea how to give "foo" all privileges?  I'd like to use that as my development account.

PS At the bottom of that page there is a message that says:  "

> Note: phpMyAdmin gets the users' privileges directly from MySQL's
>   privilege tables. The content of these tables may differ from the
>   privileges the server uses, if they have been changed manually."

Could this be a possible solution, and if so, could someone share a link that shows how to change the MySQL privilege table manually?

Comment: The accepted answer from this question worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935619/mysql-wont-let-user-login-error-1524

Answer (score 1):

OK, after hours of searching around I'm getting much closer to a solution.

It turns out that there is an error in the EasyPHP installation package that is related to changes from earlier versions of MySQL.  Here is the workaround:

(1) Open the file:
:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5711x86x160717165359\my.ini

(2) Add this line at the end and then save the file:
show_compatibility_56 = on

(3) Restart the MySQL server from the EasyPHP dashboard.

Oh yes, I also ran the following upgrade from the MySQL command line:
mysql_upgrade -u root -p

This has cleared up some errors which showed up in other tabs that I didn't mention, such as not having permission to access the server status and not being able to get a list of the MySQL variables.

I still would like to solve the original problem but have spent too much time on this initial stage to work on it tonight.  If anyone has info that please post.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. What I did to fix it was quite simple.

1. Exit `EasyPhp`.
2. Navigate to directory **\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5717x86xxx\data**
3. Find and remove the following files with ext `.frm` & `.ibd`

   ```
   innodb_index_stats
   innodb_table_stats
   slave_master_info
   slave_relay_log_info
   slave_worker_info
   ```
4. After navigate to directory **\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5717x86xxx\bin**
5. Open command prompt and type

   ```
   mysql_update -u root -p
   <BLANK>
   ```

Afterwords you should see MySQL update, aswell as some of easyphp's files.

6. Exit mysql terminal, and start EasyPhp again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Don't follow these instructions, after removing those files mysql_upgrade will fail and display the error: "[ERROR] 1146: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist" and you won't be able to repair your installation. BTW it says "mysql_update" and as far as I know that command doesn't exist, I suppose it means "mysql_upgrade "!