# Error 1524 (HYOOO) : Plugin '' is not load

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I have a problem with Mysql on a Easyphp Devserver. A power failure cause a crash of the server and now i have this message when a try to connect to the mysql command :

> ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin '*1F3EC38D27440D69A3E27CD76441C58FE0A0C3FF'
>   is not loaded

I have tried many things like this command :

> mysql_upgrade -u root -ppassword --skip-grant-tables

That i have found in this discussion [MySQL Won't let User Login: Error 1524](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935619/mysql-wont-let-user-login-error-1524)
but the --skip-grant-tables return an error :

> mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] unknown option '--skip-grant-tables'

Every time I'm trying to connect to the BDD, i have the plugin message and the command "mysqld" don't exist on my server (since many posts use that command to resolve their problem).

I'm asking myself if i have to uninstall easyphp and install it again ? Or does it have other possibilities ?
I'm a beginner with that configuration, so i may have not understand everything i have found :o

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Please note that the `authentication_string` column in the mysql.user table now stores credential information for all accounts. The Password column, previously used to store password hash values for accounts authenticated with the `mysql_native_password` and mysql_old_password plugins, is removed.
>
> If you upgrade to 5.7 MySQL release from an earlier version, you must run mysql_upgrade (and restart the server) to incorporate the changes to the mysql database. `mysql_upgrade` moves Password column values to the authentication_string column and removes the Password column.

Reference Url: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79622