# mysql can't login as root, reinstall doesnt work

Tags: mysql

I just installed mysql, but i think I did something wrong when changing root password. After the password change, I can't login as root anymore.

The error is :

```
mysql -uroot
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B' is not loaded
```

I have tried to reinstall and delete everything, but after reinstall, still can't login. It seems that the user data remain intact. Any idea how?

Additional note :
If we login with command "mysql", although we have the mysql prompt, we can't do anything, we dont have right for anything.

Thank a lot

Comment: I think this question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935619/mysql-wont-let-user-login-error-1524

Comment: @nilerafter24 Nothing of the available post work for me though. I have added skip-grant-tables in my.cnf. But how do I drop tables, if i can't login?  Running mysql -uroot still returns the same error.

Comment: @nilerafter24  I am on Mac and mysql 5.7.17 installed via homebrew. The command "mysql_upgrade -u root -ppassword --skip-grant-tables" returned an error too : mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] unknown option '--skip-grant-tables'. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

how about you download latest version of MySQL and try reinstall after remove everything. That should solve you problem as the error stated about missing plugin.

Comment: I think the error seems like a corruption of mysql user table, although I am not sure. As the plugin hash is actually a hash of user password, but entered into the wrong column, which is a plugin column. The problem here is that although I reinstall mysql, the user tables seems to be intact.