# How to remedy an accidentally installed, non-existent plugin in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-grant

Someone new to MariaDB ran a command that resulted in their being unable to log into mariadb as root. They receive the following:

```
$mysql -u root
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'xxx_password' is not loaded
```

I'm hoping someone can tell me how to fix it and what likely caused it. They were most likely trying to create a user with the username/password of xxx/xxx_password

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935619/mysql-wont-let-user-login-error-1524

Comment: For the record, @Santosh, it was not a duplicate (the plugin was human-readable - not a hash and it didn't seem to show up in the mysql.user table), but I'm not sure what was going on. I restarted the server with --skip-grant-tables, explored for a bit then restarted the machine. Subsequently it is fixed but I don't know what fixed it.